# Getting similar data from 2 tables for the same field

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have 3 tables:

- WireEnd1 (WireNo, Terminal1)
- WireEnd2 (WireNo, Terminal2)
- Terminals (Terminal, InternalPN)

The relations are between Terminal=Terminal1 and Terminal=Terminal2.

I'm trying to create a query which returns complete info:

```
SELECT 
    W1.WireNo, W1.Terminal1, T.InternalPN as InternalPN1, 
    W2.Terminal2, T.InternalPN as InternalPN2
from  
    WireEnd1 as W1 
inner join 
    Terminals as T on W1.Terminal1 = T.Terminal
inner join 
    WireEnd2 as W2 on W2.Terminal2 = T.Terminal;
```

Unfortunately it is not working. I've also tried some subqueries...not working.

Thank you for the replies.

Comment: Can you please post some sample data? Do you have a Terminal in all three tables?

Comment: define 'not working'....are you getting an error, or is it returning the results you don't want?  Also, please let us know which database you are using.

Comment: You need to clarify your `desired result, how is the `WireEnd1` table related to the `WireEnd2` table?

Comment: @Jospeh B 
A wire has 2 ends. Suppose they are different. Terminals table is the correspondence between external part number and internal part number.

Comment: @Twelfth
In MS ACcess, it doesn't return anything for Terminal2 and InternalPN2

Comment: @Lamak - WireEnd1 and WireEnd2 are related through WireNo (the same wire)

Comment: well internalPN2 that you have there is set to internalpn, which is the same as your internalpn1. I think I can guess at an answer...your joins are messed and you have a very unclear relation here. this inner join here: "inner join WireEnd2 as W2 on W2.Terminal2 = T.Terminal" You've already set T.terminal = w1.terminal1 in the join above...so this is essentially a w1.terminal1 = w2.terminal2 (which I get the feeling isn't what you are going for here). Rethink how you have your tables laid out.

Comment: Have you set up relationships between your tables?  Seems like doing that, and then using the graphical query builder, would show you how your tables want to be joined.  (IIRC it'll even let you switch to the SQL view once you're done, so you can copy the SQL if you just want to do it in code.)

Comment: First, thank you very much for your answers. I know I'm missing something, and I don't know what. First I tried only one table for Wires(WireNo,Terminal1,Terminal2) and Terminals(Terminal,InternalPN) for the correspondence between part numbers. But I need a query which returns the WireNo and external ans internal part numbers at the same time.

Comment: @cHao - I just tried the wizard mode, not working :( Once you choose the InternalPN for Terminal1 you cannot choose it again for Terminal2. The query doesn't return anything.

Comment: @FlawlessData Thank you for the clarifications. Please try my query below. I corrected the column name after I added the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    W1.WireNo, W1.Terminal1, T1.InternalPN as InternalPN1, 
    W2.Terminal2, T2.InternalPN as InternalPN2
from  
    WireEnd1 as W1 
inner join 
    WireEnd2 as W2 on W2.WireNo = W1.WireNo
inner join 
    Terminals as T1 on W1.Terminal1 = T1.Terminal
inner join
    Terminals as T2 on W2.Terminal2 = T2.Terminal;
```

Basically, you join tables `WireEnd1` and `WireEnd2` to get the data for the same wire. Then, you join each table with a copy of the `Terminals` table to get the `InternalPN` data from the `Terminals` table. You cannot join both the tables to a single copy of it, because the same row will not be equal to both Terminal1 and Terminal2. Therefore, you had not been getting any output.

Comment: A terminal very well might match both ends, if it has a wire looping back to itself.  (Which would probably be an error, at least in cases outside of high-frequency RF circuits.  But the database certainly isn't going to prevent it.)

Comment: @cHao That's correct. However, the fact that the OP did not get any data with the original query indicates that currently there is no such configuration.